# Default Windows 7 logon account picture for all users?

Tags: windows-7, login

I'm trying to figure out how to set a default Windows 7 logon account picture (the box just above the username field - looks like a picture frame) for all users.  The environment is a computer lab, with all computers on a domain - I'd like all users to see the same default jpeg or bitmap at the login screen.  I sure would have thought this would be an easy thing to do, but my google fu is failing me bigtime.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not at my Windows 7 machine right now, so I can't test this.

The default account images on Windows 7 are stored in `X:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures` where `X:\` is the system drive. You ought to be able to move all of the images from that directory and replace them with a single image file. Your image file should be 128x128 pixels.

Comment: This is part of it but it won't set this to occur for different users.  Good call on noting the pixel size required for the image though! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MMC (Start--> MMC  in the run line)

1. Add the Group Policy Object Editor via File--> Add/Remove Snap In and select it, choose local and follow it along.

   1. Then open it to Local Computer Policy,
   2. then Computer Configuration,
   3. then Administrative Templates,
   4. Control Panel,
   5. then Users Accounts
   6. finally you should see the "Apply the default user logon picture to all users".
2. Double click it and then simply set it to Enabled and hit OK.

Now if you want to use a picture different than the Windows 7 default:

Place the pic you want to use  here `%programdata%\Microsoft\UserAccountPictures\user.bmp`

<sup>*  I am pretty sure there are rules to the size of this image but you are gunna have to look those up yourself I am too lazy :)</sup>

Comment: Hey Chuck, thanks - I'd tried your instructions on one of my lab computers, but still get the blank "picture frame" box at the logon screen.

Comment: An additional note - Chuck, your instructions DO in fact, set a default user icon for all users in the start menu after logging in - when I click on the start menu, I see the same bitmap in the upper right corner no matter who logs in.  But, I still have a blank "picture frame" box at the login screen.

Comment: Did you do like Amazed suggested and ensure your image is a bmp of the appropriate size?  128 x 128 pixels or it probably won't display.

Comment: Also, I shoulda asked... but I kinda assumed from the way you put the question that we are talking a system that is not part of a domain, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you also have the "Interactive logon: Do not display last user name" GPO set to "Enabled" (under ... Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options) then you will see a blank "picture frame" box at the login screen.